# How to convert Joules(kinetic energy) plot chart into watts?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, simulation, solidworks, energy

How to convert Joules(kinetic energy) plot chart into watts?
Anyone know how?[image]

Comment: Watts are Joules per second, so area under the curve.

Comment: @SolarMike But the area under the curve would give Joules **times** seconds, which seems a meaningless quantity. Using the *slope* of the curve would be better!

Comment: Why you don't plot it in Watts? Solidworks does plot in Watts.

Comment: @SolarMike I think you're thinking of the other way around.  To get total energy from a power plot you just integrate.

Comment: Yeah; the differential is `tan( angle of the curve )` or rise rate.

Comment: What is the source of this chart?  I'm highly skeptical that it is actually showing Joules rather than Watts, since there's no easy way for the total energy to **decrease** with time.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: If that's a total *kinetic* energy, then the simple way of it decreasing over time is colliding with something. Drop an object at around 1.50, it hits the floor at ~2.15, then bounces two times before coming to a rest. (not meeting the 0 line on the moments of bounces could be blamed on sample rate and time of contact with surface being short.)

Answer (score 4):

To convert a plot of J versus s to a plot of J/s vs s, take the derivative.

Here is my quick-and-dirty answer after digitizing the data.

[image: derivative plot]

Comment: What software package[s] did you use here?

Comment: IgorThief in Igor Pro. https://www.WaveMetrics.com/.  When I would have the raw data rather than image, this would be a direct one-step process that would be accurate rather than rough.

Comment: @Chemomechanics  my favorite tool for digitizing graphs is DataThief.  It's like magic.